# Problema con mensaje programado en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Bueno mi problema esta que yo tengo esta función dentro de JavaScript:

```
(function () {

    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    c.addEventListener('click', function () {

        // VARIABLES QUE CONTROLAN LAS CAJAS DE TEXTO DEL HTML
        var x=document.getElementById("x").value;
        var y=document.getElementById("y").value;
        var z=document.getElementById("z").value;

        //VARIABLE QUE MOSTRARA COMO QUEDARA LA ECUACION...
        // REEMPLAZANDO LAS LETRAS POR VALORES AGREGADOS EN LAS
        // CAJAS DE TEXTO....
        var muestra = "3("+x+")<sup>3</sup>+10("+y+")<sup>2</sup>+"+z;

        document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = muestra;

    });
}());
```

y el HTML es este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ecuaci&oacuten</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" name="frmEcuacion">
        <div>
            <h1>Ecuaci&oacuten</h1>
            <label for="">Escriba los siguientes valores de la ecuacion: 3x<sup>3</sup>+10y<sup>2</sup>+z</label>
            <br><br>
            X: <input type="text" id="x">
            <br><br>
            Y: <input type="text" id="y">
            <br><br>
            Z: <input type="text" id="z">
            <br><br>
            <button id="c">
                Calcular
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div>   
        <p id="ecuacionN"></p>      
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calcular.js"></script>
</html>
```

Mi problema es que cuando le doy a calcular, el mensaje solo aparece una milésima de segundo y desaparece. No se como hacer para que el mensaje se mantenga.

¿Puede ser que la función debido a que se sigue ejecutando deja de mostrar?

Comment: Sería bueno [edit] tu pregunta y agregues el HTML a cambio de la imagen para poder replicar tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pagina se esta refrescando debido a que por defecto el `button` hace submit al form. Cambia el `button` por un `input` para que no haga submit y refresque la pagina:

```js
(function () {

    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    c.addEventListener('click', function () {

        // VARIABLES QUE CONTROLAN LAS CAJAS DE TEXTO DEL HTML
        var x=document.getElementById("x").value;
        var y=document.getElementById("y").value;
        var z=document.getElementById("z").value;

        //VARIABLE QUE MOSTRARA COMO QUEDARA LA ECUACION...
        // REEMPLAZANDO LAS LETRAS POR VALORES AGREGADOS EN LAS
        // CAJAS DE TEXTO....
        var muestra = "3("+x+")<sup>3</sup>+10("+y+")<sup>2</sup>+"+z;

        document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = muestra;

    });
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ecuaci&oacuten</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" name="frmEcuacion">
        <div>
            <h1>Ecuaci&oacuten</h1>
            <label for="">Escriba los siguientes valores de la ecuacion: 3x<sup>3</sup>+10y<sup>2</sup>+z</label>
            <br><br>
            X: <input type="text" id="x">
            <br><br>
            Y: <input type="text" id="y">
            <br><br>
            Z: <input type="text" id="z">
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" id="c" value="Calcular" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div>   
        <p id="ecuacionN"></p>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```